# Coding a command-line tool in Objective-C that takes inputs, clears screen and then outputs

Tags: objective-c, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I hope I'm not asking for too much here.

I would like to create a command-line tool that will run in a terminal window. It will take input from the terminal, do something with the string, clear the screen and then output strings.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{    
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog (@"Running....");

       // take the argument as an NSString
       // do something with the NSString. 
       // clear the terminal screen.
       // output the manipulated screen. 

    [pool drain];
    return 0;

}
```

Is this possible? Any tips? I would like to be coding this as much as possible in Objective-C.

Thanks,

**EDIT 1***

Just to be clear, I would like to be continuously inputting and outputting from the program.  In other words, it would be necessary to enter data after the executable has started running. Not just when it initially executes.

Comment: You could always call `exec ("/usr/bin/clear");` to clear the screen. To take input, you can use any C or C++ method such as `fscanf()` or `std::cin`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible. Use the "Command Line Tool" template in Xcode when you create your project.

A quick example could be:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        char input[50];
        while (true) {
            // take the argument as an NSString
            NSLog(@"Enter some text please: ");
            fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
            NSString *argument = [[NSString stringWithCString:input encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

            // do something with the NSString.
            NSString *uppercase = [argument uppercaseString];

            // clear the terminal screen.
            system("clear");

            // output the manipulated screen.
            NSLog(@"Hello, %@!", uppercase);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```